# How to reach end of file correctly in C

Tags: c, file

I am doing a C project related to my lesson. I need to read words from a file named file2.txt whose content:

file2.txt:

```
stephen elis elis
awkward
hello bye

stephen ayse
goodbye 
book picture pencil
```

I am using:

```
FILE *file = fopen("file2.txt" , "r");
char word[15];
while(!feof(file))
    {
        fscanf(file,"%s",word);
        printf("%s" , word);
        printf("\n");

    }
```

But when the words are printed the result is:

```
stephen
elis 
elis
awkward
hello
bye
stephen
ayse
goodbye
book
picture
pencil
pencil   --> printed second time
```

Thus , last word is printed twice and I do not understand why. Please help me about fixing this error because time is limited to complete this error!
Thank you...

Comment: **Never** with `feof`... (and *hundreds* of duplicates).

Comment: Thank you WhozCraig but still I am not sure and I did not exactly understand what will be the best solution to my problem and I am new to C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check fscanf return value

**FIX:** sorry, it should be used like this:

```
if (EOF != fscanf(file,"%s",word))
  printf ("%s\n" , word);
```

**EDIT:** Or maybe better:

```
  if (0 < fscanf(file,"%s",word))
      printf ("%s\n" , word);
```

since EOF value is (-1)

Comment: see the fix, my answer was for sscanf...